# Not able to set up "Draft" printing quality in Canon TS6120

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

I have installed the Canon TS6120 driver from the official [website](https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/support/details/printers/inkjet-multifunction/ts-series-inkjet/pixma-ts6120-black-wireless-all-in-one-inkjet-printer?tab=drivers_downloads) but I have not been able to set up the "draft" printing quality.

[Link to the printer settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFQYc.png)

In Windows, I was able to print in draft mode, but I am having some issues in Ubuntu. I am assuming they are related to the driver.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: No, I have not. It seems that the developer who created the driver forgot about this little detail.